# Confusion when displaying an image from matplotlib.pyplot to tensorflow

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytorch

I have this error: TypeError: Invalid shape (28, 28, 1) for image data

Here is my code:

```
import torch
import torchvision
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
from torchvision.utils import make_grid
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import DataLoader
from torch.utils.data import random_split
%matplotlib inline

# Load dataset

!wget www.di.ens.fr/~lelarge/MNIST.tar.gz
!tar -zxvf MNIST.tar.gz

from torchvision.datasets import MNIST

dataset = MNIST(root = './', train=True, download=True, transform=ToTensor())
#val_data = MNIST(root = './', train=False, download=True, transform=transform)

image, label = dataset[0]
print('image.shape:', image.shape)
plt.imshow(image.permute(1, 2, 0), cmap='gray') # HELP WITH THIS LINE
print('Label:', label)
```

I know that the pytorch does processing via this way: C x H x W,
and that matplotlib does it this way: H x W x C, yet when I change it to  matplotlib's way, it gives me an error here. Am I missing something? Why does this happen?

Comment: Try to squeeze the last dimension using `np.squeeze()`

Comment: Thanks this worked! Can you tell me the rationale behind np.squeeze()? Why does using this method work?

Comment: I added an answer with explanation, I suggest deleting yours and kindly accepting my answer :)

Comment: @zampoan it's weird that you tagged `tf` rather than `pt`. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.imshow()` expects 2D or 3D arrays. If the array has 3 dimensions then the last dimension should be `3` or `4`. In your case the array has shape `(28,28,1)` and this is considered as a 3D array.

So the last dimension should be squeezed out in order to match `imshow()`'s requirements.

```
plt.imshow(np.squeeze(image.permute(1, 2, 0), axis = 2), cmap='gray')
```

Comment: @zampoan this is the right and only acceptable answer. Please don't repeat the same post.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct, but doesn't use the shortest path. `image` has a shape of `[1,28,28]`. `image.permute(1,2,0)` turns it into `[28, 28, 1]` which then requires `squeeze` to turn into a `[28, 28]` shape. But a shorter answer is to just use `image[0]`